# Access VBA Boolean comparison returning wrong answer

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm doing a Boolean comparison of a single precision number passed as an argument to a single precision field in a DAO recordset. The argument is 0.85 and the field is 0.85, yet VBA says the first is less than the second. I've looked at these in the Watch window, in break mode, with Debug.Print statements and they show up as the same number everywhere. Yet VBA doesn't return TRUE when I compare A = B.

The pertinent code is below my signature.

TIA,

Keith

```
    Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT cmpAttainPct, cmpPayPct, cmpPayAmt" _
    & " FROM tblCompPlans" _
    & " WHERE [cmpPerson]=""" & DMName & """" _
    & " AND [cmpPeriod]=""" & BiPeriod & """" _
    & " ORDER BY [cmpAttainPct];"

Dim rsCompPlan As DAO.Recordset
Set rsCompPlan = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)

' Round the percent to two decimal places.
' Didn't use the VBA Round() function which uses Banker's rounding,
' That rounds .5 either up or down, whichever will result in
' an even number." (Microsoft Round() help)
' I.E.: .645 = .64 and .655 = .66
' This does standard 4/5 rounding.
AttainPct = Int(AttainPct * 1000) / 1000
Dim ThousandsPlaceValue As Single
ThousandsPlaceValue = (AttainPct * 100) - Int((AttainPct * 100))
AttainPct = (Int(AttainPct * 100) / 100)
AttainPct = AttainPct + IIf(ThousandsPlaceValue < 0.5, (-0.01), (0.01))
```

...

```
            Do Until .EOF
            Debug.Print AttainPct & " attainment equals " & !cmpAttainPct & " comp tier (" & (AttainPct = !cmpAttainPct) & ")"
            Select Case True
                Case (AttainPct < !cmpAttainPct)
                    TempAmt = PrevAmt
                    TierFound = True
                    .MoveLast
                Case (AttainPct = !cmpAttainPct)
                    ' Equal - tier found.
                    TempAmt = !cmpPayAmt
                    TierFound = True
                    .MoveLast
                Case Else
                    PrevAmt = !cmpPayAmt
            End Select
```

Comment: What are the data types of `AttainPct` and `cmpAttainPct`?  If either is a floating-point type, you should probably convert them to a fixed-point type like `Decimal` or `Currency`.  Testing floating-point numbers for equality is almost always a bug.

Comment: Both are Single. I try that in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, never use *Single* for calculations except if there is a very specific and good reason for doing so. If *Currency* can hold your values (four decimals maximum) use, else *Decimal*, and *Double* as the last option.

Second, `Int` does not do a 4/5 rounding, it rounds down. The simplest bug-free and true *4/5 rounding towards zero* you can do, is with `Format`:

```
RoundedValue = CCur(Format(ValueToRound, "0.00"))
```

For a full set of rounding functions, see:
[CodeProject: Rounding Values](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1022704/Rounding-Values-Up-Down-By-Or-To-Significant-Figur)
or:
[Experts-Exchange: Rounding values](http://rdsrc.us/NM5yNn)

With `AttainPct` rounded and converted to, say, *Currency*, you can reliably use:

```
Case (AttainPct < CCur(!cmpAttainPct))
```

and:

```
Case (AttainPct = CCur(!cmpAttainPct))
```

Comment: Experience shows you are right about the Single data type, but it seemed like a reasonable choice since I'm storing percentages and only concerned with three decimal places of accuracy. Single has range from -3.4 x 1038 to 3.4 x 1038 and up to seven significant digits.

Comment: Yes, it is fine for just storing, say, a series of - maybe millions of - measurements where each reading already has a little uncertainty. But as soon you begin subtracting (which includes comparing) values and expect precise results, you may be caught by floating point errors. That's not to blame _Single_ (or _Double_ for that matter) as it is by design and by nature of these data types.

Answer (score 1):

Computers are not very good at comparing floating point numbers for equality. Instead of

```
if a = b
```

use

```
if abs(a-b) < 0.0001
```

set the second part to as small as is necessary to make sure a small enough variation still counts as "equal".

Comment: Ah, yes. I think I have a CloseEnough() function in the snippets bucket. Thanks.

Comment: Odd, thing, though. I wrapped both values in CStr functions and compared them. They both returned "0.85", but Access still said they were not equal.

Comment: In the Immediate Window:
? abs(0.849-0.848) <= 0.001
False

Comment: That is because there are  a lot of trailing digits you so not see. You have to forget the `=` part when it comes to floating point numbers and decide how many digits it makes sense in your application to consider two numbers as different.